# How to test componentWillMount inside a connected React-Redux component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, chai, enzyme

I have the following smart component which uses componentWillMount lifecycle method to make an async call to fetch data. I am writing tests for it but I am unable to test if the function gets called and if it does it is called before the component gets mounted. They are important cases to cover.

The code for the smart component is as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {   const context = state.context;  return {
    isError: context.error,   }; };

const options = {   componentWillMount: (props) => {
    const { dispatch } = props;
    dispatch(fetchContextUser());   }, };

export function App(props) {   return (
    <div className="app">
      { props.isError ? (<ContextError />) : (<Main />) }
      { props.children }
    </div>   ); }

App.propTypes = {   children: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types   isError: PropTypes.bool.isRequired, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(functional(App, options));
```

I am using Enzyme, Chai and other mock adapters for testing this component. The test block is follows :

```
describe.only('Render Connected Component', () => {   let store;   beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      context: {
        error: false,
      },
    });   });   it('Should render connected components', () => {
    const connectedWrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedApp />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(connectedWrapper).to.be.present();   }); });
```

> I just want to test two things :
>
> 1.) fetchContextUser is called
>   2.) fetchContextUser is called before the component gets mounted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @pedro-jiminez is close, but missing two elements here:

- In order in invoke `componentWillMount` in enzyme, you need to use `mount`, not `shallow`
- That answer assumes that `fetchContextUser` is a prop, and can be replaced with a spy. In this case, you probably want to stub `store.dispatch` in your test and assert that it was called with `fetchContextUser`, assuming that's just a pure function.

So the test would look like:

```
describe.only('Render Connected Component', () => {
  let store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      context: {
        error: false,
      },
    });
    // stub dispatch
    sinon.stub(store.dispatch);
  });
  it('Should render connected components', () => {
    const connectedWrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedApp />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(connectedWrapper).to.be.present();
    // Now test dispatch called
    expect(store.dispatch.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(store.dispatch.args[0][0]).to.deepEqual(fetchContextUser());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just have to test that the `componentWillMount` method calls the `fetchContextUser` action, because you must to trust that **ReactJS** will call the `componentWillMount` method before it gets mounted, so, that premise test your second case.
So, to test the first case I think you can do something like this:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
...

it('It calls fetchContextUser when calls componentWillMount', () => {
  const fetchContextUserSpy = sinon.spy();
  const wrapper = shallow(<App fetchContextUser={fetchContextUserSpy} />);
  fetchContextUserSpy.reset(); //reset the spy to avoid unwanted calls
  wrapper.instance().componentWillMount(); // Call componentWillMount directly
  expect(fetchContextUserSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true; // Expect that after call componentWillMount() the fetchContextUserSpy was called once
```

In this test you just call directly the componentWillMount() function and expects that the fetchContextUserSpy is called, so that test your **case 1**.
I'm using **sinon.js** to test when a function is called.

Again your **case 2** not needs to be tested because **ReactJS** guarantees that the componentWillMount method is called before the component is mounted.

=========================================================================

Try this with functional component

```
it('It calls fetchContextUser when mounted', () => {
  const fetchContextUserSpy = sinon.spy();
  const wrapper = shallow(<App fetchContextUser={fetchContextUserSpy} />);
  expect(fetchContextUserSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true; // Expect that the component calls the fetchContextUserSpy
});
```

Comment: Also, I am getting an error that **wrapper.instance(...).componentWillMount is not a function**.

Comment: That can be happening because your component is a **functional component**, and that kind of components can't access to **componentWillMount** or any **life cycle method**.

Comment: Yes, it is a functional component. Any chance there is a get around for that?

Comment: Well, I think you can just test if the function is called when the component is mounted.
**I added some extra code that can help**